# Dielectric sphere

Tags: electromagnetism, dielectric

I was studying dielectric and came across a question I dont really get and never saw. I was asked to study a dielectric sphere with radius a and polarization P= Cr^2 with radial direction. I did the calculations and got a result for the electric field inside and zero for the outside,which I think is correct. But then the last question asked to check, based on the result of the electric field , the passing relations that happen at radius=a(I am translating from another language so it is a bit hard to translate exactly like it is written). I am assuming that the question if refering to vectors of the electric field and polarization, but what conclusion can I take from the vectors at the surface based on the electric field? I know there is no free charge and the charges from the surface and volume cancel each other, thats why E=0 outside, but I cant elaborate much more than that...can someone just give a hint of direction can i take with this question?

Comment: Is the last part asking that your results electric field satisfy the boundary conditions at the surface?

Comment: If it is boundary conditions, it is very simple right? because D is zero, all I have to use is the electric field?